# I'm getting an unauthorized error but my API key is working

Tags: reactjs, json, http-status-code-401

I'm following a tutorial for a react weather app. I get the API from openweathermap (it works) and still i'm getting this error.

Also I'm getting this (I don't know if it's related)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'Y', "You need t"... is not valid JSON
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at window.onload

Clearly this tutorial is over my knowledge (the API/JSON part) but I just want to understand wat's happening to finish it.

The error is thrown in the fetch line:

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon'

const API_KEY = 'MY API'
const BASE_URL = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5'

const getWeatherData = (infoType, searchParams) => {
  const url = new URL(BASE_URL + '/' + infoType)
  url.search = new URLSearchParams({ ...searchParams, appid: API_KEY })

  HERE IS THE ERROR --->return fetch(url).then((res) => res.json()) <---HERE IS THE ERROR
}

const formatCurrentWeather = (data) => {
  const {
    coord: { lat, lon },
    main: { temp, feels_like, temp_min, temp_max, humidity },
    name,
    dt,
    sys: { country, sunrise, sunset },
    weather,
    wind: { speed },
  } = data

  const { main: details, icon } = weather[0]
  return {
    lat,
    lon,
    temp,
    feels_like,
    temp_min,
    temp_max,
    humidity,
    name,
    dt,
    country,
    sunrise,
    sunset,
    details,
    icon,
    speed,
  }
}

const formatForecastWeather = (data) => {
  let { timezone, daily, hourly } = data
  daily = daily.slice(1, 6).map((d) => {
    return {
      title: formatToLocalTime(d.dt, timezone, 'ccc'),
      temp: d.temp.day,
      icon: d.weather[0].icon,
    }
  })

  hourly = hourly.slice(1, 6).map((d) => {
    return {
      title: formatToLocalTime(d.dt, timezone, 'hh:mm a'),
      temp: d.temp,
      icon: d.weather[0].icon,
    }
  })

  return { timezone, daily, hourly }
}

const getFormattedWeatherData = async (searchParams) => {
  const formattedCurrentWeather = await getWeatherData(
    'weather',
    searchParams,
  ).then(formatCurrentWeather)

  const { lat, lon } = formattedCurrentWeather

  const formattedForecastWeather = await getWeatherData('onecall', {
    lat,
    lon,
    exclude: 'current,minutely,alerts',
    units: searchParams.units,
  }).then(formatForecastWeather)

  return { ...formattedCurrentWeather, ...formattedForecastWeather }
}

const formatToLocalTime = (
  secs,
  zone,
  format = "cccc, dd LLL yyyy' | Local time: 'hh:mm a",
) => DateTime.fromSeconds(secs).setZone(zone).toFormat(format)

const iconUrlFromCode = (code) =>
  `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${code}@2x.png`

export default getFormattedWeatherData

export { formatToLocalTime, iconUrlFromCode }
```

Thanks!

I just want to understand why it is happening this when that is no what happens in the tutorial i'm seeing.

Comment: This is your `package.json` file, you're probably trying to parse an API response from a Weather Service and their response is not a valid JSON. Try to check the network tab in your browser and inspect the responses for any XHR requests.

Comment: _"Unexpected token 'Y', "You need t"... is not valid JSON"_ - that indicates that instead of JSON, together with the 401 status code, you got a response body that contains _plain text_, starting with `You need t` - and the _rest_ of that is probably telling you, what you need to do, in regard to that 401. So go and check what that full message has to say, by inspecting the response via your browser dev tools.

Comment: This is your package.json file and provides no value in understanding your problem. This is like saying, "I have a problem with my Windows PC, here is a windows CD, please help." Please post sample code that's causing the error.

Comment: Your error is being thrown in other part, not in your package.json.  Share us the react part in which you consume the openweathermap api. Also attach us a success response from  postman

Comment: I edit the post. I put the js file where the error appears